# UWP Release build on .NET Native tool chain throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: win-universal-app

When perfoming a Release build for our UWP project the following error occurs:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class Result=1).
```

And a second issue:

```
error CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
```

I tried to reproduce the issue with a new solution but I cannot figure out the dependencies responsible for those issues.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with Entity Framework Core RC1. If we remove the EF dependencies the Native Tool Chain works as expected... It seems that there are some Workarounds https://imbushuo.net/archives/318

Comment: The issue is fixed with Entity Framework Core RC2